# RPC Server error when trying to link Windows Live ID

Tags: windows-7, rpc

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit. When i try to link my Account to Windows Live ID i get a RPC Server not available Error. From services.msc the RemoteProcedureCall (RPC) is running and is set to automatic. I can't get any more details from the Error i am getting. I tried also to discontinue Windows Firewall and Avira Antivirus and then tried again, but i get the same problem. I saw many problems over the internet about RPC but none did relate to my problem. It is not as if i am dying to connect to my live ID, but i am curios to find out why this is happening. Has anyone experienced the same problem ? Does anyone know how to get a more detailed exception on this so we can see what actually is happening ? Or has someone a workaround ? Any help is appreciated.

[image: Windows ID]

[image: Windows ID RPC Server not Available]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to this error. Many suggest to turn off firewall and antivirus, other suggest to copy HWDeviceLogin.dll from another PC where linking with Windows ID is working, there are also some who suggest to type msconfig and to set the start on normal or modify the registry. In some occasions this might do the trick but it is actually a workaround.

The actual problem is that before you can connect your Windows Live ID to your account you must accept the Windows Live agreement. In windows search type Windows Live and then click on Windows Live Mesh, hear just click on accept (Agreement) and then close the Windows Live Mesh. Now try again to link your account to Windows Live ID, it should be working.

The problem hear was the Error massage. You get a RPC Server is not available Massage when actually the service is running on automatic and it is available. The Error Massage should be something like Please accept the Windows Live Agreement.

I am posting the answer hear cause this solution migh help others.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just start Windows Live mail and log in with your Windows Live id. As soon as your logged in you can go back to control panel, user accounts and connect your Live id to your local user account.

This will probably not work if the user account is located in a domain.